# Kony SPA application not loading in browser - HTTP ERROR: 500

Tags: temenos-quantum

i am new to Kony, i have build a simple app for iPhone and SPA, the build is successful but the SPA url is throwing an error as below, please help what could have gone wrong.

error

HTTP ERROR: 500

Channel not build
RequestURI=/Gestures/p

```
Caused by:

com.kony.web.exception.ChannelNotFoundException: Channel not build
    at com.kony.web.controller.KonyWebCommon.processRequest(KonyWebCommon.java:125)
    at com.kony.web.controller.KonyWebCommon.processDoRequest(KonyWebCommon.java:110)
    at com.kony.web.controller.KonyWebCommon.doGet(KonyWebCommon.java:234)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1097)
    at com.konylabs.middleware.common.DCFilter.doFilter(DCFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1088)
    at com.kony.web.filter.KonySPADetailsFilter.doFilter(KonySPADetailsFilter.java:69)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1088)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:320)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:829)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the project, select Properties, increment the version and then open the Target Platform tab. Make sure that Phones - Mobile Web Channel / HTML5 Single Page Apps (SPA) is checked.

Then make sure that your project has a mobile form. And right-click on the project again, select Build -> Clean and Build and check Web / HTML5 SPA. After the build, right-click one more time and Publish the mobile web channel.

Comment: Yes, My form was missing in the desktop, i just create a new form and everything started working as expected. But i have some new problems, probably will open up a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

If to use the SPA project in a browser with the URL:

```
http://ipadress:8888/appid/p
```

You have to change the device mode in the developer tool. Than it works.

[Device Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVg8Q.png)

Greeds
Falk

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12162872)

Comment: Now it's an answer. Thanks for the advice, and sorry about the circumstances.